# Can't call function from componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication

Inside componentDidMount() i'm checking firebase.auth to see if user has authenticated, if yes this should be calling multiple functions ("this.functionName()") however this doesn't work and results in yellow box: "[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.loadChallenge')]" They are located under the same class.

```
componentDidMount() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

      //if user exists
      if (user) {
        console.log('Auth triggered.')
        this.loadChallenge()
        this.activateListener(user.uid)

        console.log('User is logged in ... profile.')
      } else {
        console.log('Not signed in.')
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "arrow function" syntax rather than function keyword to preserve the value of `this` for your callback function. So the function will have access to the methods on your component class.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

```
componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

        //if user exists
        if (user) {
            console.log('Auth triggered.')
            this.loadChallenge()
            this.activateListener(user.uid)

            console.log('User is logged in ... profile.')
        } else {
            console.log('Not signed in.')
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I've made it less elegant way by creating new arrow function that is called from within the normal function which then calls the other two functions, but this is definitely the way to go!

Comment: You could have also used `.bind()` to pass in the the `this` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: For majority of my time working with react, I was avoiding working with functions so haven't got to learn most of these things. I used bind for something else before but definitely arrow function makes this way more clear